# Could somebody help to identify this shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I saw this shrub in the gardens of a stately home and loved it.  Could anyone help me identify it?  Thanks!

[image: shrub closeup][image: whole shrub]

Comment: It's Calico Aster. Botanical name is Symphyotrichum lateriflorum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a variety of Symphyotrichum lateriflorum, a clump forming perennial plant, previously called Aster lateriflorum. Image of a similar variety here https://www.bethchatto.co.uk/s-z/symphyotrichum/aster-lateriflorus-prince.htm